# ZedGraph, numbers gather in a region of number line when graph is scaled

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I scale graph but I have problem like in the image (http://postimage.org/image/74ra418yv/). 
This is a simulation window, so each pointpairlist is calculated for each unit time. I don't show all of them at the same time. So I create CalculateScale Function for scaling. I need minimum X,Y and maximum X,Y in all lists. I finds minimum and maximum value of x-axis and y-axis with CalculateScale. It works good, only problem is numbers are gathered in a region.

```
public void EditScale(List<PointPairList> lists)
{
    GraphScale scale = CalculateScale(lists);
    GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = scale.MinX - 20;
    GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = scale.MaxX + 20;
    GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = scale.MinY - 20;
    GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = scale.MaxY + 20;
}

protected GraphScale CalculateScale(List<PointPairList> list)
{
    double maximaY = -10000000;
    double minimaY = 10000000;
    double maximaX = -10000000;
    double minimaX = 10000000;
    double listMinY, listMaxY, listMinX, listMaxX;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        listMaxY = list[i].Max(point => point.Y);
        listMinY = list[i].Min(point => point.Y);
        if (listMaxY > maximaY)
            maximaY = listMaxY;
        if (listMinY < minimaY)
            minimaY = listMinY;
        listMaxX = list[i].Max(point => point.X);
        listMinX = list[i].Min(point => point.X);
        if (listMaxX > maximaX)
            maximaX = listMaxX;
        if (listMinX < minimaX)
            minimaX = listMinX;
    }

    return new GraphScale(minimaX, maximaX, minimaY, maximaY);
}
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code that you used to produce the referenced screenshot?  That would make it easier for someone else to help you out.

Comment: You right, so I add sample code and the problem still unsolved :)))